# Make C Program for Interactive Mode

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth, obex

Here I have one command which is like interactive mode:

```
obex_test -b $BD_ADDR $CH_NUM
```

This command is from a script but I want to run this command through a system call in a C program.
`obex_test` is nothing but obex file transfer library.
Here I want to receive a file from remote device to local device through bluetooth.
This is the manual page of [obex_test](http://www.digipedia.pl/man/doc/view/obex_test.1/)

Please can anybody tell me how can I put my C program in interactive mode like this command, and I want to use this command also.

I used `popen(command,"r")` but its not useful; it does not take input from the user.
If I used `"w"` mode then I don't know what happens; I directly get a message like `>Unknown Command`.  It's the error this command gives when we give different options. So it's taken something as a write mode.

Answer (score 1):

You could have two pairs of pipes (created with the [pipe(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) system call); one for data from your program to `obex_test`'s *stdin* and one from `obex_test`'s *stdout* to your program. Then you would `fork` and `execve`... Beware of deadlocks (your program blocked on writing to `obex_test` *stdin* when its output pipe is full and blocking it), you might need to call [poll(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) or `select(2)`...

However, as it man pages explain, "`obex_test` is a test application for the `libopenobex` library". So why don't call directly functions inside this [libopenobex](http://dev.zuckschwerdt.org/openobex/) library, which you would link to your program?

Comment: Can u give me any Example of this pipe concept? please Explain me i am beginner

Comment: Read any standard book on Linux or Unix programming to learn more about pipes, processes, .... But in you case, I strongly suggest using the `libopenobex` library; For unix programming http://basepath.com/aup/ and for Linux programming http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Comment: oki i will go with library way. i will find openobex library and have to change this thing.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the system command. Check the manual page for more details. 
For e.g. system( "obex_test -b 172.16.7.1 1234" );

Comment: But After Execution i have to give input something

Comment: @user1089679 yes, isn't that what you meant by "interactive mode"?

Comment: i am not asking here how to use system call . i am asking here interactive mode.